# How to create a RESTful webservice in Xamarin and Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, android, web-services, xamarin, windows-phone

I am currently trying to find a solution on how to create (not consume!!!) a RESTful service with Xamarin for Android and on Windows Phone. I already searched for it, but only found libraries and solutions on how to consume a RESTful webservice on those platforms.
Do you know any good library to create a webservice on those platforms or any hints on how to implement a simple werbservice (not using ASP.NET)?

TIA Octo

Comment: you want to run a webservice on your mobile device?

Comment: Yes. Sounds strange, but I have no other choice in this situation.

Comment: Could you provide a little more information on what is driving the need for a RESTful webservice on the device?

Comment: I need to call methods on the device with different parameters and receive their response for testing purposes. The idea was to use JSON for object serialisation and a REST service, which I can call from the host system. If there is another idea, which will work on at least Android and Windows Phone, I am open for it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xamarin.NET and WinRT frameworks (and their package ecosystems) have pretty comprehensive support for web services etc. from a client perspective, but not so much if you want to act as the host. You can't install something like webapi or signalr host into a PCL, or even the native platform projects.

Based on your clarification comments, I would suggest one of the two approaches below. I will assume that the RESTful requirement is more of a "nice to have", and the "calling methods with parameters and getting results" is the priority.

**1. Make the mobile apps clients too** - remove the hosting requirement from the mobile devices by adding a hub on another server with the full .NET profile. Both your mobile apps and your "test runner" connect to this and the hub routes the messages between them. SignalR would handle this easily. This option is not at all RESTful and requires an additional server, but is quick to get up and running and will easily support your desire to pass json messages back and forth.

**2. Go lower level** - Use sockets to facilitate communication directly between the mobile devices and "test runner". The mobile devices can open sockets for listening, and your "test runner" connects to them direct. Again, not RESTful and a bit more involved - you need to define a (hopefully) simple protocol (e.g. {length of type name}{type name}{length of payload}{payload}) and use that to send send and receive json - but it avoids needing a middle machine for routing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to use HttpListener and it works (after I figured out port forwarding for the Android emulator), so I took your second option and went lower level :-). This solution should be enough and was fairly simple to implement.

Comment: Good! I don't think HttpListener is available in the WinRT (Windows Phone) framework though. You can use StreamSocketListener on WinRT, but that again is TCP sockets so you may need handle http requests from the client by hand if you want to use the same code on the test runner. Alternatively, you take sockets as the lowest common denominator and use the native APIs, or try [sockets-for-pcl](https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl) (disclaimer: my library and it's quite new) which abstracts over .NET/WinRT to a common API you can use in a PCL too. But then you need your own protocol again!

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with the .NET Framework 4.0. Would it be possible to support .NET 4.0 in your PCL, too?

Comment: Hadn't thought about that.. I don't think there is any real dependency on 4.5 besides of course async/await which hopefully can be overcome with Microsoft.Bcl.Async. I'll look into it over the next few days..

Comment: That would be great. Thanks :-)!

Comment: Just so you know, I did take a look at relaxing the target to 4.0 but got stuck and had to leave it. I'm going to do a bit of research and look into it again for the next version..